# datatable export not working javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a datatable to which i add the export functions {pdf,xls,copy,print,excel}.
my problem is that all of them are not working. When i press 'pdf' nothing happens, if i press 'xls' or 'excel' it creates an empty excel file, and if i press 'copy' it gives me "table copied 0 rows".

i looked at a lot of code samples, and also took some working samples as they are, but also it didn't work.

can someone check what am i doing wrong!!

here is my javascript that i use to add the buttons to my table:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var oTable = $('#tblMessagesDetail').DataTable({
            "bPaginate":true
        //,"oLanguage":{"sUrl":"E:/WWW/Scripts/de_DE.txt"}
        ,"bJQueryUI":true
        ,"sPaginationType":"full_numbers"
        ,"sDom":'T<"clear">lfrtip'
        ,"oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "single"
        ,"sSwfPath": "../Scripts/DataTables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" 
        ,"aButtons": ["copy","print",{"sExtends":"collection","sButtonText": "Export Options","aButtons":["copy","print","csv", "xls", "pdf" ]}]
        }
        });
        new FixedHeader( oTable );
    });
```

and this is my table:

```
  <table id="tblMessagesDetail" class="table table table-hover table-striped  table-condensed export-table" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>                      
                    @ViewRes.SharedStrings.SmsID
                </th>
                <th>                      
                    @ViewRes.SharedStrings.CustomerName
                </th>
                <th>                       
                    @ViewRes.SharedStrings.ProjectName
                </th>
                <th>                       
                    @ViewRes.SharedStrings.Account
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].MSISDN)
                </th>
                <th>                      
                    @ViewRes.SharedStrings.smsStatus
                </th>
                <th>                       
                    @ViewRes.SharedStrings.SendDate
                </th>
                <th>                       
                    @ViewRes.SharedStrings.SentDate
                </th>                    
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.SmsList)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Account.Project.Customer.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Account.Project.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Account.Login)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MSISDN)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.SmsStatus.Value)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SendDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.SentDate)
                    </td>                      
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <td>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("FillDetailModal", "Statistics", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <button id="btnDetails" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-@item.SmsMTId">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i> @ViewRes.SharedStrings.btnDetails
                            </button>
                        }

                        <div class="modal fade" draggable="true" id="myModal-@item.SmsMTId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div id="modalDialog" draggable="true" class="modal-dialog" style="padding-bottom:0px">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #428bca; color: white; ">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                            &times;
                                        </button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                            Message Detail ID: '@item.SmsMTId' - Ticket #@item.SmsMT.Ticket - Project @item.SmsMT.Account.Project.Name
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <table style="width:100%; " border="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">

                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMT.Id)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Id)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">

                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMT.Account.Project.Customer.Name)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Account.Project.Customer.Name)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">

                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMT.Account.Project.Name)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Account.Project.Name)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].MSISDN)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MSISDN)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMT.SmsStatus.Value)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.SmsStatus.Value)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMT.EventReason)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.EventReason)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SendDate)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SendDate)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMT.SentDate)

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.SentDate)

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMT.Ticket)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMT.Ticket)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].ExtId)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExtId)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMTContent.NotificationLevel)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMTContent.NotificationLevel)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMTContent.OADC)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMTContent.OADC)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SmsList[0].SmsMTContent.Message)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SmsMTContent.Message)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                            Close
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: does it complain in the console? do you have the file TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf in the specified path?

Comment: yeah i have the file in the right place.

Comment: i found my error, apparently the modal that is in the table is blocking the save procedure, once i deleted the modal popup it worked.. now does any one have any idea how can i add data to the exported file but not to the table?!! i have fields that i dont want to put in the table but i want in the saved file